# ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute 'creator_id' for Event

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :created_events, :foreign_key => "creator_id", :class_name => "Event"
end

class Event < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :creator, :class_name => "User"
end
```

When I attempt to create an event with a creator, it says `ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute 'creator_id' for Event.`
I run `rails db:migrate` but still it doesn't create foreign key and add to events table. What am I doing wrong? I looked at everywhere.

$ rails db:migrate:status

```
 Status   Migration ID    Migration Name
--------------------------------------------------
   up     20170625163737  Create users
   up     20170625170905  Create events
   up     20170625171959  Add description to event
   up     20170625174531  Add creator id to events
```

However, migration file shows that no addition was made:

```
class AddCreatorIdToEvents < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
  end
end
```

Comment: What does `rails db:migrate:status` return?

Comment: Can you update the question with the migration file for creating events table. You would find it under `your_app/db/migrate`.

Comment: @SebastiánPalma added.

Comment: @Kranti added. It does basically nothing.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't defined association properly. Your model should look like below:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :events, :foreign_key => "creator_id", :class_name => "Event"
end

class Event < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :creator, :foreign_key => "creator_id", :class_name => "User"
end
```

Also `foreign_key` always present in child table. try create event like below.

Considering user already logged in.

```
current_user.events.create(event_params)
```

Please refer [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#bi-directional-associations) for association related helps.

Comment: `>> u.events.create(description: "trying to create")
NoMethodError: undefined method 'events' for #<User:0x000000051313c0>
 from (irb):2`

_Also foreign_key always present in child table. try create event like below._

are you sure this is right?

Comment: I have updated association in my answer. Now it will work. I have changed has_many :created_events to has_many :events in user model.

Comment: it now says `ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute 'user_id' for Event.
 from (irb):2`

Comment: I have updated my answer. We need to define foreign key in association in case of custom foreign key. Because by default rails look for association_id in child table. In this case it is looking for user_id in events table.

Answer (score 0):

Your model should look like:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :created_events, :foreign_key => "creator_id", :class_name =>    "Event"
end

class Event < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :creator, :foreign_key => "creator_id", :class_name => "User"
end
```