# ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError (unknown attribute 'product_id' for Property.):

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I am struggling with this error.  While building a react on rails project.

> Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 75ms (ActiveRecord: 6.1ms)
>   ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError (unknown attribute 'product_id' for >Property.):

When I run this controller:

```
class SendDataController < ApplicationController
    protect_from_forgery with: :null_session

    def save
        product = Product.create(name:params[:name], upc:params[:upc].to_i, available_on:params[:availableon])

        property = product.Properties.build(name:params[:properties][0][:name])
        property.save    
    end    
end
```

I have tried to things found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44752772/activemodelunknownattributeerror-unknown-attribute-creator-id-for-event) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48334075/activemodelunknownattributeerror-unknown-attribute-when-seeding-belongs-to-re).  But I am getting no where.  Below is my current setup.

Models:

```
class ProductProperty < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :Property
  belongs_to :Product
end

class Product < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :Properties
  has_many :ProductProperties
end

class Property < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :Product
  has_one :ProductProperty
end
```

Migration:

```
class CreateProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :products do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :upc
      t.datetime :available_on

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class CreateProperties < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :properties do |t|
      t.string :name

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class CreateProductProperties < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :product_properties do |t|
      t.string :value

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class AddProductRefToProperties < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    add_reference :properties, :Product, foreign_key: true
  end
end

class AddProductRefToProductProperties < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    add_reference :product_properties, :Product, foreign_key: true
  end
end

class AddPropertiesRefToProductProperties < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    add_reference :product_properties, :Property, foreign_key: true
  end
end
```

Schema:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2018_09_24_163027) do

  create_table "product_properties", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "value"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer "Product_id"
    t.integer "Property_id"
    t.index ["Product_id"], name: "index_product_properties_on_Product_id"
    t.index ["Property_id"], name: "index_product_properties_on_Property_id"
  end

  create_table "products", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.string "upc"
    t.datetime "available_on"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "properties", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer "Product_id"
    t.index ["Product_id"], name: "index_properties_on_Product_id"
  end

end
```

Thanks for any help you can give me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError (unknown attribute 'product_id' for
>   Property.)

It says there is no `product_id` in `properties` table. That is true because you have `Product_id` instead of `product_id`, so is the error.

**Rails Conventions**

By default, **attribute names** should be **snakecase**. You should generate a migration which will change `Product_id` to `product_id` and migrate as to fix the error. You should also change association names to snakecase as well. For instance

```
belongs_to :Property
belongs_to :Product
```

should be

```
belongs_to :property
belongs_to :product
```

Comment: could you show me an example of how to accomplish this? 

>You should generate a migration which will change Product_id to product_id